# pytest fixture for certain test cases

Tags: pytest, fixtures

Having a testclass and testcases like below:

```
class TestSomething():
    ...
    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def before_and_after_testcases(self):
        setup()
        yield
        cleanup()

    def test_abc_1():
        ...
    def test_abc_2():
        ...
    def test_def_1():
        ...
    def test_def_2():
        ...
```

Problem is, `before_and_after_testcases()` would run for each testcase in the test class. Is it possible to let the fixture apply to testcases with `abc` pattern in the function name only? The fixture is not supposed to run on `test_def_xxx`, but I don't know how to exclude those testcases.

Comment: remove `autouse=True` and then use `@pytest.mark.usefixtures('before_and_after_testcases')` to decorate those functions -- or split it into two classes are my suggestions

Comment: Thank you, @AnthonySottile. Would you please convert your comment to the answer so that I can select it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `autouse=True` fixture is automatically applied to all of the tests, to remove that auto-application you'll remove `autouse=True`

but now that fixture isn't applied to any!

to manually apply that fixture to the tests that need it you can either:

1. add that fixture's name as a parameter (if you need the value that the fixture has)
2. decorate the tests which need that fixture with `@pytest.mark.usefixtures('fixture_name_here')`

Another approach is to split your one test class into multiple test classes, grouping the tests which need the particular auto-used fixtures

---

disclaimer: I'm a `pytest` developer, though I don't think that's entirely relevant to this answer SO just requires disclosure of affiliation

Comment: By the way, Anthony, if the fixture has an `self` arg, should the decorator for the test cases be written as `@pytest.mark.usefixtures('self.fixture_name_here')`? Testing shows `self` is not needed in the decorator, though.

Comment: nope, the fixture name is the name of the function itself